# Use Elgato Game Capture HD60S to capture Ubuntu screen shows only green screen

Tags: ubuntu, screen-recorder

I am trying to capture video output of ThinkPad T410 running Ubuntu 16.04 using Elgato HD60S. Recording is done on a Windows 10 PC. However the Game Capture program shows and records only solid [green screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wu5A.png).

- Recording from third (windows) PC works ok.
- Elgato is recognized in Ubuntu screen setup, and different resolutions can be selected. All with same result.
- HDMI output from Elgato to Samsung TV correctly shows Ubuntu desktop and reports 50 Hz, i.e. less than the 60 Hz maximum limit.

Any ideas?

**Update** Elgato support just say they don't support any Linux. Is there really a difference between video output depending on the OS? I tried my old slow PC with dual boot. Both Windows and Linux output can be recorded there.

Comment: did you just change the recording PC or maybe also one or more HDMI Cables?

Comment: PC doing the recording is unchanged. PC being recorded is changed. Also cable from this PC to elgato changed (display port output vs hdmi output). Cable seems to work fine, since Ubuntu desktop can be seen on TV from elgato HDMI output.

Comment: ok thats exactly why i asked there are different Versions of HDMI (http://denon.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/192/~/differences-between-hdmi-versions-1.1%2C-1.2%2C-1.3a%2C-1.4-and-2.0%3F) and those also take changes of the Cable with them not about the pinout or the Connector but about the used Material of the Cables inside and the Shielding inside the Cable itselfs. My first Guess would be that there is a Problem with a Cable using a to low Version so it doesn't support the Resolution you use. 2nd is HDCP (High Definition Copy Protection) enable on one of the PCs but not on the other.

Comment: @konqui How can it be a cable problem if ther cable works towards my TV (both through elgato and directly)?

Comment: don't ask me which technical detail exactly makes the difference but there is one i had a nearly equal problem and changing the cables to two with HDMI Version 2.0 worked thats all i can say. Or try out a input splitter and go to the capture card and the tv parallel

Comment: 50Hz on the TV makes it sound like the computer is outputting a PAL signal and not an NTSC one. See if the software allows you to change the frequency it is looking for or change the setting on the computer to 60Hz and save it (might need to do it blind), and then try it with the recorder?

Comment: if HDCP is enabled on the device to be captured, then the elgato device will not be able to record, regardless of whether the recording pc also has HDCP enabled